# TCP timeouts when performing a lot of http requests in GCP VM

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, tcp, timeout, google-compute-engine

I have a host (jenkins-builder) running in the Google Cloud Platform. I'm running on Debian Buster, the VM is behind the NAT gateway.

If I execute many HTTP requests to some external host, for instance, http://example.com - source host networking will be "blocked" for a certain time == 30 seconds.

I've captured traffic via tcpdump, and now I can see that there are no ACK packets during time "blocked" time:
http://app.ep4sh.cc/paste/MLxciufIus

I do see multiple [S] but lack of [ACK] - I've double-checked the behavior on the neighbor hosts - there is no such issue on them. So in my opinion it's a particular host issue.

I've also tried to perform curl command with ---trace, please see the output:
http://app.ep4sh.cc/paste/nAbkcHNiXL

I wonder why does it try to accomplish IPv6 connection (I double-checked it is disabled):

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf  | grep -vP "^#"

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Could somebody suggest how to find out the root cause?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I was managed to clone the VM and assign the External IP address to the cloned VM. The weird issue was gone. I wonder how Google Cloud limit works in that case

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in Google Cloud Nat Gateway settings,
in my case the NAT Gateway was created by Terraform, by default Terraform provider enables Endpoint Independent mapping (which differs from the Google cloud docs):

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_router_nat#enable_endpoint_independent_mapping

That makes sense why only 64 connections were available for any foreign host. It was a default value for port allocation.